# Visa Reward card "use or lose" fee -- where is that forbidden?

Tags: visa, reward-program, gift-card, expiration

Just got a non-reloadable $5 Visa RewardCard. While it is imprinted "funds do not expire" on the front, the back says:

"Except where prohibited by law, a Monthly Fee of $2.50 per month will be applied to the remaining balance on this card beginning in the 12th month following the date of activation."

I seem to remember that Massachusetts is one of the states which does forbid this kind of "it doesn't expire but it evaporates" fee. Can anyone confirm that, and/or tell us whether there's a list of which states do prevent issuers from pulling this stunt?

(I can burn it off easily enough; one workaround is to immediately use it to buy non-expiring store credit. I'm just grumpy about their attempt to cheat around the gift-card expiration laws.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the terms and conditions sheet. See [this example here](https://www.cumoney.com/Docs/cumoney_GIFT_website_GC_Fee_Info_English.pdf) that states:

> States where inactivity fees are not applied: Arizona, Connecticut, Hawaii, New York and Vermont

Comment: That makes too much sense...